# Change event participant status by clicking on a link (via civimail)

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

I created a new participant registration status called "Attending" for participants to let me know that they are actually planning to come to the event.

I currently do this by emailing registered participants a link to a Drupal Webform (that includes: ?cid1={contact.contact_id}&{contact.checksum})

Once they click the link, I have the form set so that if they click the submit button it changes their registration status from registered to attending without having to fill out any fields.

Is there a way to accomplish this just by having them click on the link in the email, without having to go to the webform and click submit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what you can do is to add in your webform a bit of javascript to automatically click on the submit button, eg in the body of the webform (or anyway you want to add some javascript):

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
  $(".form-submit").click();
});
</script>
```